# How to avoid this kind of circular dependency?

Tags: python, refactoring, global-variables

I have a global(not a class) python module called **Controller**, which imports **ClassA** and **ClassB** for intantiating. I also import **Controller** inside **ClassA** and **ClassB** for updating the global variable.

```
from Controller import setElement
from Tkinter import *

ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        setElement("Oval")
        root.mainloop()

ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        setElement("Round")
        root.mainloop()
```

---

```
from subclasses import ClassA, ClassB

_element = None

def setElement(element):
    _element = element
    check()

def check():
    if _element == "Round":
         instance = ClassA

    elif _element == "Oval":
         instance = ClassB
```

So is there a very easy way to refactor it. I dont want to move the global variable into a new file and then checking with a while true loop if the variable has changed. I have read about observers, but I think(hope) there is a simpler method.

Comment: You're class definitions are incorrect, and your `import` statement in the second block of code cannot work either. Were you trying to do a `from block1 import A, B`?

Comment: This was just an example to demonstrate my problem. I forgot to write from*. eddited-

Answer (score 0):

how bout

```
def check():
    if _element == "Round":
         instance = __import__("ClassA")

    elif _element == "Oval":
         instance = __import__("ClassB")
```

and get rid of the import at top?

Comment: but one problem still exists. In my ClassA/B I get the follwoing error: instance = getattr(import_module("ClassA/B") 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassA/B'. So a import loop still exists.